# Building a multi-dimensional associative R array for JSON

Tags: arrays, json, r

I have a large data table which I want to transform into an array. The array should reorder the data table such that all observations matching a column's unique value are provided as appended lists/vectors.

I will provide a manually written .js example of what I mean below, if this is unclear, but here is what I attempted with R using a smaller dummy data set:

```
library(dplyr)
#get random data
test <- read.table("http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/data/test.txt", header = TRUE)
print(test)
#Remove duplicate values of test & unwanted columns and save in new data.frame (test2)
test2 <- select(test[!duplicated(test[,5]),], 5:6)
print(test2)
```

What I'd like to do is create an array where test's observations are added as lists/vectors by associating test$schtyp's values with test2$schtyp's values.

Can someone help me out? Here's what I endeavor to create

```
var JSON = [  {
"latitude":40.621111,
"longitude":-80.435278,
"countryName":"United States",
"countryCode":"USA",
"reactors": [
  { 
    "reactorUnit":"SHIPPINGPORT",
    "latitude":40.621111,
    "longitude":-80.435278,
    "type":"PWR",
    "unitPower":60,
    "capacity":68,
    "status":"Permanent Shutdown",
    "operator":"DOE DUQU",
    "reactorSupplier":"WH",
    "license":null,
    "construction":19725,
    "criticality":20821,
    "grid":21156,
    "commercial":21331,
    "shutdown":30225
  },
  {
    "reactorUnit":"DOUNREAY DFR",
    "latitude":58.57814,
    "longitude":-3.75233,
    "type":"FBR",
    "unitPower":11,
    "capacity":15,
    "status":"Permanent Shutdown",
    "operator":"UKAEA",
    "reactorSupplier":"UKAEA",
    "license":null,
    "construction":20149,
    "criticality":21868,
    "grid":22920,
    "commercial":22920,
    "shutdown":28185
  }
]},{
"latitude":44.143333,
"longitude":4.709444,
"countryName":"France",
"countryCode":"FRA",
"reactors": [
  {  
    "reactorUnit":"G-2 (MARCOULE)",
    "latitude":44.143333,
    "longitude":4.709444,
    "type":"GCR",
    "unitPower":39,
    "capacity":43,
    "status":"Permanent Shutdown",
    "operator":"COGEMA",
    "reactorSupplier":"SACM",
    "license":null,
    "construction":20149,
    "criticality":21387,
    "grid":21662,
    "commercial":21662,
    "shutdown":29253
  },
  {
    "reactorUnit":"CALDER HALL-3",
    "latitude":54.4205,
    "longitude":-3.4975,
    "type":"GCR",
    "unitPower":49,
    "capacity":60,
    "status":"Permanent Shutdown",
    "operator":"SL",
    "reactorSupplier":"UKAEA",
    "license":null,
    "construction":20302,
    "criticality":21186,
    "grid":21245,
    "commercial":21306,
    "shutdown":37711
  },
  {
    "reactorUnit":"CALDER HALL-4",
    "latitude":54.4205,
    "longitude":-3.4975,
    "type":"GCR",
    "unitPower":49,
    "capacity":60,
    "status":"Permanent Shutdown",
    "operator":"SL",
    "reactorSupplier":"UKAEA",
    "license":null,
    "construction":20302,
    "criticality":21520,
    "grid":21641,
    "commercial":21641,
    "shutdown":37711
  }
]
```

Please let me know, if you don't understand what I'm trying to say. I'd appreciate some help on this!

Best, naibaf!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you nest columns before converting to JSON, you can do what you want:

```
library(tidyr)
library(jsonlite)

test %>% nest(prgtype:ses) %>% toJSON() %>% prettify()
```

returns

```
[
    {
        "schtyp": 1,
        "level": 1,
        "data": [
            {
                "prgtype": "general",
                "gender": 0,
                "id": 70,
                "ses": 4
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "schtyp": 2,
        "level": 1,
        "data": [
            {
                "prgtype": "vocati",
                "gender": 1,
                "id": 121,
                "ses": 4
            },
            {
                "prgtype": "academic",
                "gender": 0,
                "id": 172,
                "ses": 4
            },
            {
                "prgtype": "academic",
                "gender": 0,
                "id": 113,
                "ses": 4
            },
            {
                "prgtype": "general",
                "gender": 0,
                "id": 50,
                "ses": 3
            },
            {
                "prgtype": "academic",
                "gender": 0,
                "id": 11,
                "ses": 1
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "schtyp": 3,
        "level": 1,
        "data": [
            {
                "prgtype": "general",
                "gender": 0,
                "id": 86,
                "ses": 4
            },
            {
                "prgtype": "vocati",
                "gender": 0,
                "id": 141,
                "ses": 4
            }
        ]
    }
]
```